# Unable to type username in an application after opening it from cmd using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pyautogui

I want to open an application and type username into that application.
But my username is getting typed in the command window that too after closing that application.
If I uncomment the commented lines below, then username doesn't get typed(none other application is open).

Please help.

```
  import subprocess, pyautogui
  subprocess.call('C:/a-b/a-b.exe')
  pyautogui.typewrite('username'+ '\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why my above code is not working. However, I have found another way to perform the required task:

```
import pyautogui, time
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'esc');
pyautogui.typewrite('a-b');
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite('username' + '\t');
pyautogui.typewrite('password' + '\t');
pyautogui.press('enter')
```